# Mega-Menu dropdown doesn't display on hover?

Tags: theme, css, menu, drop-downs

I am using Magento 1.9x with Ultimo Theme.
There is a small issue with my mega-menu display on hover.

- Dropdown Menu on hover displays fine [here](https://styroshop.com)
- But menu doesn't display on hover when I am at [this page](https://styroshop.com/holiday-bundles)

Can you please help and propose a solution? Please guide which html/css files to edit as I am very new to Web developmen, thank you!

Comment: where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a javascript issue on your page. You have used `"ramadan kareem" english 2d letters (75w x 25h x 5t) cm"` for an option. Change `"ramadan kareem"` to `'ramadan kareem'`

Comment: Wow this worked like magic, but how did you find where the problem was?

Comment: If you check your browser console, it will show you all javascript related errors. There was a string break in JSON string when you used double quotes in you option title.

Comment: Great, got it. Can you help me with one more thing please:
In my category views I can only see 8 products like [here](https://www.styroshop.com/products) or [here](https://www.styroshop.com/holiday-bundles)
How do I change the number of products by default, what if I want to show all the products on one page?

Comment: To change that value, go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Products per Page on Grid Default Value` refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33186149/1409718